# Understanding of the FGSM attack by Goodfellow et al

Tags: machine-learning, gradient, adversarial-example

The authors of the paper "*Explaining and harnessing adversarial examples*" (ICLR'15) give the following rationale for taking the sign of the gradient of the loss with respect to its inputs in Section 4 of the paper:

> We can linearize the cost function around the current value of $\theta$, obtaining an optimal max-norm constrained perturbation

I am trying to understand what they mean by this. Do they mean that they find a linear approximation with a first-term Taylor expansion? I do not see how that leads them to take the sign in the FGSM attack formulation.